# Displaying Filled Markers with scatter3 in Octave while using a colormap

Tags: octave, scatter-plot

Using the following, I am able to get a 3D scatter plot in Octave:

```
figure()
scatter3( ...
    plot_data(:, 2),  ...
    plot_data(:, 3),  ...
    plot_data(:, 4), ...
    % Marker size ...
    9, ...
    % Color data using colormap ...
    plot_data(:, 1)
    );
colormap(copper())
shg
```

However, the markers are not filled. Alternatively, I could increase the `linewidth` but I have no idea how to do this in Octave when I am using `colormap` syntax.

How do I adjust the `scatter3` call above to either fill the markers or increase the `linewidth`?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the `filled` option. Use the following when calling `` `scatter3 () `` independently of the colormap you then select:

```
scatter3 (plot_data(:, 2), plot_data(:, 3), plot_data(:, 4), 9, plot_data(:, 1), "filled");
```

Comment: I actually already tried that before posting. I get the following errors: `error: invalid color specification: flat` and
`error: invalid value for color property "markerfacecolor" (value = flat)`

Comment: @ChrisRedford works for me. What OS, Octave version and graphics_toolkit are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive this, but I had the exactly problem today. I solved it attributing a fake color scale and then plotting:

```
vet_x = rand(1,100);
vet_y = rand(1,100);
vet_z = rand(1,100);
size_scale = linspace(1,10,length(vet_x));
fake_color = linspace(1,10,length(vet_x));

scatter3(vet_x,vet_y,vet_z,size_scale,fake_color,'filled')
colormap('copper')
```

Hope this helps.